# Is it possible to quote/escape command line arguments on Windows while linking setargv.obj?

Tags: c++, windows, glob

I am linking my C++ program with setargv.obj to get [wildcard expansion working on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/expanding-wildcard-arguments). Do you know whether it is possible to quote/escape asterisk (*) somehow to avoid expanding it? None of the following works as one would expect (i.e. leave the asterisk and just strip the quotation/escape character): `"*"`, `'*'`, `\*`. Or is something like this unsupported by the setargv.obj?

Comment: No, it calls `expand_argument_wildcards` on every argument that contains "?" or "*" wildcard characters. The expansion itself is via WinAPI `FindFirstFile` which translates the pattern to a native NT wildcard pattern for the `NtQueryDirectoryFile` system call. None of these levels implements any kind of escape character.

Comment: That's a pity. OK, thank you.